# Swapfile does not load when hibernating in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, hibernate

Many articles seem to have been dedicated to installing hiberate under Ubuntu 18.04 x64 / Kernel 4.20. But, I still cannot get my system loading the swapfile after hibernation. This is what I did:

1. Install hibernate GNOME [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5/alternative-status-menu/)
2. Create new swap file of 16GB

`sudo swapon --show`

> NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
>
> /swapfile file  16G   0B   -2

3. Update `etc/default/grub`

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/sda1
> resume_offset=15140864"

4. Update to kernel 4.20

After these actions the systems does go into hibernation but, never loads the old system state.

Is there anything I am overlooking here?

Comment: Are swap files supported for hibernation now? At least a while ago, you could only hibernate to swap partitions, but swap files were not supported. Not sure if that has changed yet.

Comment: Check `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` is configured, then do `sudo update-initramfs -c`. Why the offset in your GRUB line? Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation here. I've just tried with UUID and it worked like a charm:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=d2175d30-aee3-418b-8c3f-d4ae61d13b3f resume_offset=2367488"

Hope it helps,
Br,
Martin